# Laravel : How to get all users who have a certain role?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have three roles: 1. `Admin` 2. `Client` 3. `Store`

I have three tables: 1. `users` 2. `roles` 3.`role_user`

How can I get all users who have the role `Client`?

I tried this

```php
$clients = User::roles()->where('App\Models\Role',Role::CLIENT)->get();
```

I'm getting following error.

> Non-static method App\Models\User::roles() should not be called
>   statically

**Role Model**

```php
class Role extends Model
{
    public const ADMIN = 'Admin';
    public const CLIENT = 'Client';
    public const STORE = 'Store';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User')->using('App\Models\UserRole');
    }
}
```

**User Model**

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'activated',
        'token',
        'signup_ip_address',
        'signup_confirmation_ip_address',
        'signup_sm_ip_address',
        'admin_ip_address',
        'updated_ip_address',
        'deleted_ip_address',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function hasRole(String $roleName)
    {
        return $this->roles()->where('name', $roleName)->exists();
    }

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role');
    }

    public function addRole(String $roleName)
    {
        $role = Role::where('name', $roleName)->first();

        if ($role) $this->roles()->save($role);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you defined the relationships between User and Role models?

Comment: I just added code of my model tp question, should I also need to add userRole model code?

Comment: No it's not needed and @N69S has already answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `whereHas()` method. it's a way to condition on relation using `exists` in query

```php
$clients = User::whereHas('roles', function($role) {
    $role->where('name', '=', Role::CLIENT);
})->get();
```

If you want to get the role too, stack the `with()` method

```php
$clients = User::whereHas('roles', function($role) {
    $role->where('name', '=', Role::CLIENT);
})->with(['roles' => function($role) {
    $role->where('name', '=', Role::CLIENT);
}])->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working.  is there any more optimized solution available?

Comment: @KishorPatidar well, depends on why you need all the clients. if it's just to count them, run `->count()` instead of `->get()`. if you are displaying them, use `->paginate()` instead and make your client list paginated.

Comment: Yes I am using `paginate` instead of get. I was just comparing two solutions one from you and other from  @caddy-dz.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're trying to call the `roles` method on the Model class and not the instance, here's how it should be

```php
$clients = Role::whereName('client')->first()->users;
```

Comment: This solution will send two requests to get the results. but it should work fine